# Refactor assignment in a Kotlin way

Tags: kotlin

There is a variable:

```
var itemDecorators: MutableList<ItemDecorator>? = null
```

At the very beginning of a function I'm trying to do the following:

```
private fun draw(c: Canvas, rv: RecyclerView, vh: ViewHolder) {
    val decorators = itemDecorators ?: return
    if (decorators.isEmpty()) return
```

Is it possible in Kotlin to refactor the last two lines into one statement, i.e. check if not `null`, check if not empty and then assign, otherwise `return`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val decorators = itemDecorators?.takeUnless { it.isEmpty() } ?: return
```

Comment: exactly that was looking for!

Comment: Absolutely world class @Vadzim. This is clean